# Pointers and debugging in golang

Tags: go

I'm stuck in a situation and cannot figure out what I messed up. Easiest way to explain is probably some minimal example: http://play.golang.org/p/14lbOBsCCo

I am tying to modify a value of a struct via its pointer but end up modifing some memory other the part I want. Line 92 is where my issue is.

How would you debug a situation like this (tools etc.), and how do I get the broker.Port set?

Thanks for hints/suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using pointers throughout. Start off with a Registry of type:

```
type Registry []*Broker
```

and work from there

[Working example](http://play.golang.org/p/Na2y4XYKlT)

As far as debugging tricks, this was my process:

- Value isn't being changed, so something is being copied by value
- Notice that Registry is type `[]Broker`, but we want to modify Brokers, so it needs to be a pointer
- Change `type Registry` to `[]*Broker`
- Keep attempting to compile, letting the compiler tell me every place we are using a value where we need a pointer (woohoo fast compile times and static typing)

Comment: That's it! Your answer is almost as demeaning as "let me google this for you" :) Thanks!

Comment: I added a little more info, but sometimes it's the simple things ;)